# error: unrecognized arguments while using ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I am using the following code snippet to take in user arguments

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-k', '--keywords', help='something', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
search_keyword = [str(item) for item in args.keywords.split(',')]
```

When i give the input as `-k bears,elephants` it works fine but when i give `-k polar bears,elephants` it gives me `error: unrecognized arguments: bears,elephants`

this is clearly the space character being considered as a separate item. How do i resolve this?

Comment: How about `-k "with space,bears,elements"`

Comment: thanks for your response. but I did not want user to know there has to be "". Anyway without it?

Comment: Almost all (if not all) command line tools separate arguments using space. If your argument has space in it. You must quote it. Most beginners will quickly learn about this.

Comment: BTW, in your message, you said `-k polar bears,elephants` gave errors with has *baloons* in it--where does *baloons* come from?

Comment: As @HaiVu suggested, you must quote any arguments that contain a space (or any other special character, such as a vertical bar, semicolon, or exclamation point): -k 'polar bears',elephants